# Netty dynamic range port?

Tags: java, netty

How can I specify range port use by netty tcp server on dynamic port exchange with multi clients?

I start my server like this:

```
 bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
 workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(20);
 ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
 b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup).channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class).handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
                .childHandler(new SocketServerInitializer(serverHandler));
```

But I don't see where I can specify port range?